# Line to intersection in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reproduce the following figure in TikZ:

[image]

The two vectors are $(-1/5, 2/5), (2/5, 1/5)$. Is there a way to have TikZ draw the dotted lines till the intersection with the thick outer box, and avoid having to actually calculate the intersection points and explicitly input the nodes? So far I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (-1, 2) {};
    \node (b) at (2, 1) {};

    \draw [very thick] (-5, 0) -- (5, 0);
    \draw [very thick] (-5, -5) -- (5, -5);
    \draw [very thick] (-5, 5) -- (5, 5);

    \draw [very thick] (-5, -5) -- (-5, 5);
    \draw [very thick] (0, -5) -- (0, 5);
    \draw [very thick] (5, -5) -- (5, 5);

    \draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (a);
    \draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (b);

    \node[label=right:{$1$}] at (5,0) {};
    \node[label=above:{$1$}] at (0,5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I'd simply clip the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you'd get a better result using polar coordinates (and especially not using `node` to define points a and b, but `coordinate` instead).

[image: tilted grid]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \draw[rotate=30,dotted,orange,cap=round] (-10,-10) grid[step=2cm] (10,10);
        \end{scope}
        \coordinate (a) at (30:2) {};
        \coordinate (b) at (120:2) {};
    
        \draw [very thick]  (-5, -5) rectangle (5, 5)
                            (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$1$}
                            (0,-5) -- (0,5) node [above] {$1$};
    
        \draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (a);
        \draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (b);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The vectors are no longer at the coordinates given in the question. atan(1/2)=26.57°

Comment: Yes, I know, and your version is more accurate on this point, but it was not clear if their coordinates were mandatory. The whole thing gives the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `grid`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (-1, 2);
\coordinate (b) at (2, 1);    
\draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (a);
\draw [very thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (b);
\node[label=right:{$(1,0)$}] at (5,0) {};
\node[label=above:{$(0,1)$}] at (0,5) {};
\draw[very thick, step=5] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[dashed, very thick, step=sqrt(5), rotate=atan(1/2)] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rotated grid with two vectors]

Comment: `dashed` can be replaced by `dotted`